# Table-capture doesn't handle new line

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm trying to `table-capture` this in an org file

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113
127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173
179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229
233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281
```

but I keep getting this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    2|    3|    5|    7|   11|   13|   17|   19|   23|29 31|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   37|   41|   43|   47|   53|   59|   61|   67|71 73|   79|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   83|   89|   97|  101|  103|  107|  109|  113|  131|  137|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |  127|     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  139|  149|  151|  157|  163|  167|  173|  181|  191|  193|
|     |     |     |     |     |     |  179|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  197|  199|  211|  223|  227|  229|  239|  241|  251|  257|
|     |     |     |     |     |  233|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  263|  269|  271|  277|  281|     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So at every new line, it's not recognizing the return/new line. When it asks for row delimiter I just hit enter, which is no doubt my problem. What should I give for row delimiter -- or what else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a NEWLINE as the row delimiter regexp: you do that by typing `C-q C-j` - the `C-q` quotes the subsequent character so that it loses its special meaning; `C-j` is a newline (the end-of-line delimited on Unix/Linux - you may have to do something different on Windows).

This is explained in the "Inserting text" section of the Emacs manual: you can get to it with `C-h i g(emacs)inserting text`.

Comment: It worked as you said in a clean `emacs -Q`, but I can't seem to shake the doubling up on the last number of one row with the first of the second in my regular setup.

Comment: What does `C-h c C-q` say in your regular setup? It should say `quoted-insert`. If that's the case, then I would edebug `table-capture` and examine what the `row-delimiter-regexp` is as I step through the first few lines of the function (up to the `let*` on line 3648). Alternatively, bisect your init file to find out the culprit. BTW, I just noticed that the doc string of `table-capture` explicitly mentions the `C-q` quoting trick: `C-h f table-capture`.

Comment: The variable is actually `row-delim-regexp`, not `row-delimiter-regexp`.